# *ngIf Placing Comment When False

Tags: angular

I noticed when I have a *ngIf that evaluates to false, it is inserting a blank HTML comment instead of the element
Is there a way to stop it from doing this?

```
e.g.
<!---->
```

Comment: No, this is part of the Angular compiler.

Comment: No. This `<!----->`should be somewhere in your code. May be bad closing of comments

Comment: OK, thanks
Just being OCD on having as clean HTML as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already was mentioned in comment this is part of the Angular compiler.

`*ngIf` is a structural directive that can be expanded to

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="someValue"></ng-template>
```

`ng-template` is represented by `EmbeddedView`. For each EmbeddedView angular compiler [creates](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/view/element.ts#L15-L40) `anchorDef` with element like:

```html
element: {
   ns: null,
   name: null,
```

Then angular [creates Comment node](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/view/element.ts#L156) for elements with `null` name

```typescript
export function createElement(view: ViewData, renderHost: any, def: NodeDef): ElementData {
  ...
  if (view.parent || !rootSelectorOrNode) {
    if (elDef.name) {
      el = renderer.createElement(elDef.name, elDef.ns);
    } else {
      el = renderer.createComment('');
    }
```

In dev mode angular also [stores bindings](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/core/src/view/services.ts#L384) in this node:

```typescript
function debugCheckAndUpdateNode(
    view: ViewData, nodeDef: NodeDef, argStyle: ArgumentType, givenValues: any[]): void {
      ...
      if (!elDef.element !.name) {
        // a comment.
        view.renderer.setValue(el, `bindings=${JSON.stringify(bindingValues, null, 2)}`);
      }
```

so we can see in our rendered DOM something like this:

```typescript
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}-->
```

And the main purpose for having this comment node is this way angular knows where embedded view will be placed in DOM.